# How to Count the frequency of specific words for each column using R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am using this dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Eco-hotel

I am trying to figure out how to count the frequency of certain words like "room" or "vacation" within each column. I have attempted following tutorials online, but unfortunately, I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the iris dataset as an example,
what you can do is:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ sum(str_detect(., 'setosa'))))
```

Of course, you‘d need to change the seqrch term to what you need.

If you want to have dedicated columns for each of your search patterns, you could alternatively do sth. like:

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 y = sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE))

df |> 
  summarize(across(c(x, y), ~sum(str_count(., c("u"))), .names = "{.col}_u"),
            across(c(x, y), ~sum(str_count(., c("g"))), .names = "{.col}_g"))
```

Here I'M searching for letters "u" and "g", respectively.

Comment: Your first lines were what I was looking for. Is it possible to do the same thing but this time with ROWS and not columns? @deschen